# Filtering an ObservableCollection to multiple list boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

In my project I currently have an `ObservableCollection` that is populated inside of my `ViewModel` constructor. This `ObservableCollection` holds a custom object which has two properties (both strings).

Currently, the XAML/View counterpart holds two separate list boxes, both of which are bonded to a `DataTemplate` that selects which property to display as an entry in the `ListBox`. In this case it displays 'propertyOne'.

Is it possible to have a `DataTemplate` that can select where each `ListBox`-item goes to depending on the content of 'propertyTwo'?

I have looked into examples similar to my situation, which used `CollectionViewSource` but I am not too sure as to how I would implement this into my project, as I am fairly new to using WPF and following the MVVM structure. Would this involve creating a filter event in the code-behind the View?

Listed below are snippets of my code that I think would be useful in understanding my question. Any help on solving this would greatly be appreciated.

## View

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=propertyOne}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate> 
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxOne"
         Height="Auto"
         Width="Auto"
         ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}" />

<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTwo"
         Height="Auto"
         Width="Auto"
         ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}" />
```

## ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> TestCollection { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //populates the collection from an XML file
        //with propertyOne & propertyTwo for each item

        TestCollection = CustomObjectClass.DeserializeToColl<Item>("path");
    }
}
```

## CustomObjectClass

```
public class CustomObjectClass
{
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Making sure I got your question - you want the second `ListBox` to show propertyTwo?

Comment: Think you need to rephrase the question. Perhaps even adding an example with desired output.

Comment: No. The list boxes will still display propertyOne, but it is propertyTwo that decides which 'ListBox' it goes to.

e.g. if the custom object has the string "read" set as it's 'propertyTwo', that object (with it's propertyOne being displayed in the 'ListBox') is sent to 'ListBoxTwo'.

Comment: The only thing i can think of in pure xaml is setting the visibility to collapsed in a style with a datatrigger... so you add all to the 2 listboxes but the container is simply collapsed. other than that you need to do some code behind

Comment: 1. Is `CustomObjectClass` mutable (i.e. setters are public and the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface)?
2. Which version of WPF is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=propertyTwo}" Value="read">
                            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=propertyOne}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: add another template for the second list like this and exchange value in the datatrigger

Comment: Tried this and it seems to work. From what I understand this will basically hide the value that is indicated next to `Value=`.